# MySQL Find differences in stock levels between two tables and return the result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables, the first is yesterdays stock levels called "**yesterday**" and contains two columns:

```
StockNumber, StockLevel
```

The second table is today's stock levels called "**today**" and has the same columns "StockNumber, StockLevel".

My question is, how do I find the differences in stock levels between the "yesterday" and "**today**" tables for both "**StockLevel**" changes and new "**StockNumber**" appearing in the "**today**".

If this can be done with straight SQL that is great, but adding an extra level of processing using PHP is also OK

Comment: Yes it can be can be done in SQL - give it a go. If you have problems with the produced SQL post it as a question.

Comment: Can a `yesterday` stock level *not* appear in `today`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select y.StockNumber, t.StockLevel - y.StockLevel from yesterday as y inner join today as t on (y.StockNumber = t.StockNumber)
```

edit:

to capture products in the today table which weren't in the yesterday table:

```
select y.StockNumber, t.StockLevel - coalesce(y.StockLevel,0) from yesterday as y right join today as t on (y.StockNumber = t.StockNumber)
```

The coalesce ensures that if you have a product which isn't in `yesterday`, you'll get `t.StockLevel - 0` instead of `t.StockLevel - NULL`

Comment: '...both "StockLevel" changes **and new "StockNumber" appearing in the "today"**.'

Comment: If the stock number changed from yesterday to today, there'd be no way to join them!

Comment: @Ian, ah the stock numbers would stay the same, just that if a new stock number was added in the "today" table, for that new stock number to be identified and the stock level for that stock number & level to be returned as well.

Comment: easy enough, just right join on the today table, so you get a row for every product in today.  This won't show you anything which was REMOVED in the today table, but that seems to be ok for your use case.  Also note that you'll need to nvl or coalesce to account for the null.  I'll update my post with a new query.

Answer (score 1):

This will let you know the change from yesterday, returning null for stocks that are new for today (ie there is no change from yesterday to display)

```
SELECT t.stocknumber, t.stocklevel-y.stocklevel difference
FROM today t
LEFT JOIN yesterday y
  ON t.stocknumber = y.stocknumber
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f1d04/7).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can find out the differences between the stock level of yesterday and today using following sql.

```
select y.stockNumber, (t.stockLevel-y.stockLevel) as difference
from today t, yesterday y,
where t.stockNumber=y.stockNumber
group by t.stockNumber,t.stockLevel,y.stockLevel
```

Hope this helps.