# Mysql return only records that have differences between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

This is an extension of the earlier [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15051242/mysql-find-differences-in-stock-levels-between-two-tables-and-return-the-result) here

I have two tables, yesterday and today and in each table there are two columns

```
StockNumber, StockLevel
```

How do I find out

1. Only the StockNumbers that have differences in their StockLevel's
2. Return the affected StockNumber & StockLevel values

For example:

todays table :

```
StockNumber, StockLevel
ABC, 10
CBA,5
123,5
```

yesterdays table :

```
StockNumber, StockLevel
ABC, 9
CBA,5
123,10
```

To return the following wi

```
StockNumber, StockLevel
ABC, 10
123, 5
```

Noticing now StockNumber "ABC" is returning todays value 10 and StockNumber "123" is also returning todays value 5 and StockNumber "CBA" there was no change and is not returned.

Many thanks,

Matt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will do it for stocks that existed both days;

```
SELECT t.StockNumber, t.StockLevel
FROM today t
JOIN yesterday y
  ON t.StockNumber=y.StockNumber
 AND t.StockLevel <> y.StockLevel
```

If you (as in your earlier question) also want the new stocks from today included;

```
SELECT t.StockNumber, t.StockLevel
FROM today t
LEFT JOIN yesterday y
  ON t.StockNumber = y.StockNumber
WHERE y.StockNumber IS NULL 
   OR t.StockLevel <> y.StockLevel
```

[An SQLfiddle to test both with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/93488/8).

Answer (score 0):

You can join the tables on StockNumber and select those rows `WHERE NOT A.StockLevel = B.StockLevel`.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit tricky, because you might have different items in the two tables.  I recommend a union all and group by for this:

```
select stockNumer,
       max(case when which = 'yesterday' then stocklevel end) as yesterdaylevel,
       max(case when which = 'today' then stocklevel end) as todaylevel
from ((select StockNumber, StockLevel, 'yesterday' as which
       from yesterday
      ) union all
      (select StockNumber, StockLevel, 'today' as which
       from today
      )
     ) t
group by stockNumber
having min(StockLevel) <> max(stockLevel) and count(*) = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select T.StockNumber, T.StockLevel 
from Today as T 
left join Yesterday as Y 
on T.StockNumber = Y.StockNumber 
WHERE T.StockLevel <> Y.StockLevel
```

play with the results here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/367b0/3/0

Answer (score 0):

The following query will return stocks that are either different (by `StockLevel`) from yesterday, or didn't exist yesterday (this is what `LEFT` and `IS NULL` are for):

```
SELECT Today.*
FROM Today LEFT JOIN Yesterday
    ON Today.StockNumber = Yesterday.StockNumber
WHERE
    Today.StockLevel <> Yesterday.StockLevel
    OR Yesterday.StockLevel IS NULL
```